# Rotate Unicode Character in R

Tags: r, unicode, rotation, flextable

I am trying to use the unicode character for ӿ R, but would like it to be rotated by 90 degrees. I want it to appear rotated in various visualizations(flextables and ggplots), so I need it to be rotated in the base dataframe that will underlie those visualizations. Also, if the rotated shape is available as a unicode character on its own, please let me know (I haven't been able to find it).

Here is my current code:

```
my_data <- 
  data.frame(shape_name = "fancy x",
             shape = "\u04ff")

flextable(my_data)
```

And the current output:

[image: flextable output]

My desired shape:

[image: desired shape]

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe [this is close enough](http://shapecatcher.com/unicode/info/119321)?

Comment: Maybe [`✱` _Heavy asterisk_](http://shapecatcher.com/unicode/info/10033)? Or [`✲` _Open Centre Asterisk_](http://shapecatcher.com/unicode/info/10034)?